# Show $P(U>1)=1$ where $U=max(\frac{X}{Y},\frac{Y}{X})$

Tags: probability

Show $P(U>1)=1$ where $U=max(\frac{X}{Y},\frac{Y}{X})$.

I know that $P(U \leq 1) =0$, and

$ 1-P(U \leq 1)= P(U>1)$

therefore, $1-0=1$

Is there any other way to show this?

Comment: If $X = Y = 1$, then $U = 1$, so you'll need to say something about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to be able to make any statement about $P(U > 1)$.

Comment: the joint distribution is $1/a$ where $0<x<a$ and $0<y<a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true for non constant, nonnegative random variables with $P(X=Y)=0$ and the convention $X/0=Y/0=\infty$. Then either $X/Y>1$ or $Y/X>1$, except on a set of measure 0. So the result follows.

Comment: do you mean continuous function?

Comment: Consider X and Y being outcomes from tossing two independent fair coins where for each head = 1 and tail = 2. Then P(Y/X)=1 = 0.5 and P(U>1) = 0.5.